# How to prepare VOTT JSON dataset to retrain COCO SSD Tensorflow api?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api

Hi I have annotated multi object dataset and exported as tensorflow format in VoTT. however I have no clue how to use it with tensorflow api.

Vott produces json file for each annotated images as follows:

> ```
> "asset": {
>     "format": "jpg",
>     "id": "0b1e1aac9a6f2cc4e51d95ef368dbfe7",
>     "name": "lemon160.jpg",
>     "path": "file:/Volumes/Solix/Datasets/limedata/imgs_raw/lemon160.jpg",
>     "size": {
>         "width": 1280,
>         "height": 720
>     },
>     "state": 2,
>     "type": 1
> },
> "regions": [
>     {
>         "id": "HWaHAokRV",
>         "type": "RECTANGLE",
>         "tags": [
>             "Expired Lime"
>         ],
>         "boundingBox": {
>             "height": 362.8564453125,
>             "width": 510.81555834378923,
>             "left": 625.7465495608532,
>             "top": 355.5866350446429
>         },
>         "points": [
>             {
>                 "x": 625.7465495608532,
>                 "y": 355.5866350446429
>             },
>             {
>                 "x": 1136.5621079046425,
>                 "y": 355.5866350446429
>             },
>             {
>                 "x": 1136.5621079046425,
>                 "y": 718.4430803571429
>             },
>             {
>                 "x": 625.7465495608532,
>                 "y": 718.4430803571429
>             }
>         ]
>     }
> ```

}

can somebody suggest me a way to convert these files to tfrecords?

Comment: did you find any script?